# Django template CSS/IMG is "off" in the URL

Tags: django, django-templates

I have

```
/path/to/my/theme/static/css/frontend.css
```

which is called by base.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/frontend.css" media="all" />
```

In which I've got a background for the header:

```
#header-wrapper 
        min-width: 960px;
        height: 150px;
        background: transparent url(img/header-bg.png) repeat-x center bottom;
}
```

The file is

```
/path/to/my/theme/static/img
```

I've run manage.py collectstatic to gather the files and almost everything looks correct except the link generated looks like: http://example.com/static/css/img/header-bg.png

In which the image does not show, because the correct URL is: http://example.com/static/img/header-bg.png

Where am I going wrong??

Comment: url() is relative to the css file's path: Maybe you could use `url(../img/header-bg.png)`. Idk.

Comment: @jpaugh: Why not change that comment into a proper answer? I'd say it's the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`url()` is relative to the css file's path: Maybe you could use `url(../img/header-bg.png)`